# How can I get info immediately when I use ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I want to get some info about live stream.

I use 
`ffprobe -i rtmp://****.`
(`ffmpeg -i http://****`) also can't get info immediately.

for some live stream,I can get some info immediately.
like this:

`Input #0, flv, from 'http://hdl.9158.com/live/2f6c6ce0162f6af2cccadf289dfa9674.flv':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Subtitle: text
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 540x960, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 1k tbn`

but
sometimes I can't get info until 2mins later, although the live stream has no problem.

how can I solve this problem.

use

`ffprobe -analyzeduration 500k -probesize 100k -i rtmp://***`

can solve the problem.
but then I run command to merge live streams I checked alive before.

`ffmpeg -analyzeduration 500k -i http://flv80f29ef7.live.126.net/live/8c79ace747b24694a8d6563c9e626509.flv -analyzeduration 500k -i http://flv80f29ef7.live.126.net/live/8c79ace747b24694a8d6563c9e626509.flv -analyzeduration 500k -i http://flv80f29ef7.live.126.net/live/8c79ace747b24694a8d6563c9e626509.flv -analyzeduration 500k -i http://flv80f29ef7.live.126.net/live/8c79ace747b24694a8d6563c9e626509.flv -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=640x480 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright]; [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft]; [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];[tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2]; [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 " -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live`

calls error:

`Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright];[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];[base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];[tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];[tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];[tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240 matches no streams.`

Comment: Add the analyzeduration and probesize options to the input with a low value.e.g. `-analyzeduration 500k -probesize 100k -i rtmp://...`

Comment: Add the options before each input.

Comment: @Mulvya Sorry for bothering. But if I add the options, my merge request doesn't work fine. It says: Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph ... matches no streams.

Comment: Show the full command you tried.

Comment: Don’t include the analyse and probe options to ffmpeg, just ffprobe.

Comment: Ffmpeg need to wait until the Weber sends the first keyframe. If analyse finishes befor that, it may assume there is no video in the stream

Comment: @szatmary So, I can only wait to merge multiple live stream into one? It's too slow...

Comment: Then decrease the keyframe interval.

Comment: @szatmary I add `-x264-params keyint=120:scenecut=0` option before every live stream, but it still doesn't work...How can I decrease keyframe interval...

Comment: @szatmary I search in stackoverflow, and I only find -x264-params keyint=120:scenecut=0 to decrease the keyframe interval,but it doesn't work...can you help me? thx.

Comment: @Mulvya I use the command to merge live streams but It's too slow to parse live stream. My full command is on my question, please pointed out my problem...